# How do I use dictionaries to manipulate variables based on the user's combo box selection?

Tags: c#, dictionary

Here is my dictionary code.

```
int numOfPlayers;
double multiplier;

Dictionary<string, Stats> games = new Dictionary<string, Stats>();
games.Add("Runescape", new Stats(1.5, 20));
games.Add("Maplestory", new Stats(1.0, 25));
games.Add("League of Legends", new Stats(1.3, 15));
```

Here is my stats class

```
class Stats
{
    public double Muliplier { get; private set; }
    public int NumberOfPlayers { get; private set; }

    public Stats(double multiplier, int numberOfPlayers)
    {
        Muliplier = multiplier;
        NumberOfPlayers = numberOfPlayers;
    }
}
```

Since I don't really know much about dictionaries, how do I use it so I can set the value of my variables in the class based on what the user selected in the combo box?

Ex: If the user selects "Runescape" it would help me set the value of `numOfPlayers` to 20 and `multiplier` to 1.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get data from `Dictionary` using *array-like* indexer access:

```
string name = "Runescape";
Stats stat = games[name];
```

However, it will throw an exception when no item associated with given `name` exists. You can make it handle that kind of cases using `TryGetValue`:

```
Stats stat;
if(games.TryGetValue(name, out stat))
{
    // stat found within the dictionary
}
```

Comment: Since I added both blocks of code in this answer, it's giving me an error since `stat` already exists. Do I use `Stat stat` or `stat` on my second block of code?

Comment: You don't need both. You have to choose one.

Comment: So I made the first stat. The problem here is that `Stats.Multiplier` or `Stats.NumberOfPlayers` does not work when I type it in the main class.

Comment: Actually I found a way to make it work. Thanks :) Basically use `string name = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();` and then for the if statement use `multiplier = stat.Muliplier;` and so on.